# How to send data to the event hub using partition key in python?

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I'm looking to send data to the Azure event hub using partition key in python and I have done it using partition ID

```
sender=client.add_sender(partition="0")
```

Since by using partition ID is not recommended, how can I send data using the partition key

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44427622/how-to-send-message-to-azure-event-hub-with-amqp-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from the [`SAMPLE REPO`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-uamqp-python/blob/2f60b23f4a0b2a764987ed972636ddb7657e07ef/samples/test_azure_event_hubs_receive.py) using PartitionKey:

```
result = uamqp.send_message(target, msg_content, auth=get_plain_auth(live_eventhub_config))
```